# use same struct for both create and update operations in go lang using gin and gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

*Disclaimer: go lang noob here*

I've my user struct as

```
type User struct {
    ID        uint32    `json:"id"`
    FirstName string    `json:"firstName" binding:"required"`
    LastName  string    `json:"lastName"`
    Email     string    `json:"email" binding:"required,email,uniqueModelValue=users email"`
    Active    bool      `json:"active"`
    Password  string    `json:"password,omitempty" binding:"required,gte=8"`
    UserType  string    `json:"userType" binding:"oneof=admin backoffice principal staff parent student"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`
}
```

`/POST /users` handler

```
func Create(ctx *gin.Context) {
    user := models.User{}
    //validate
    if err := ctx.ShouldBind(&user); err != nil {
        response.Error(ctx, err)
        return

    }
    db, _ := database.GetDB()
    db.Create(&user)
    // removing password from the response
    user.Password = ""
    response.Success(ctx, user)
}
```

I want to create an update handler using the same struct, is there any way I can perform using the same struct ?

Mind you, struct has required bindings on many fields `firstName,email` etc.
while updating, I might not pass these fields

I came up with something like

`/PUT /users/` handler

```
func Update(ctx *gin.Context) {
    userID := ctx.Param("userId")
    user := models.User{}
    db, _ := database.GetDB()
    if err := db.First(&user, userID).Error; err != nil {
        response.Error(ctx, err)
        return
    }
    updateUser := models.User{}
    if err := ctx.BindJSON(&updateUser); err != nil {
        response.Error(ctx, err)
    }
    //fmt.Printf("%v", updateUser)
    db.Model(&user).Updates(updateUser)
    response.Success(ctx, user)
}
```

this is failing obviously due to required validations missing, if I try to update, let's say, just the `lastName`

Comment: Have you tried `BindJSON(&user)`? i.e. passing in the `user` instance representing the current, just-retrieved-from-db user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try for this case to bind to the `User` struct you just pulled out of the database, like so:

```golang
func Update(ctx *gin.Context) {
    userID := ctx.Param("userId")
    user := models.User{}
    db, _ := database.GetDB()
    if err := db.First(&user, userID).Error; err != nil {
        response.Error(ctx, err)
        return
    }
    if err := ctx.BindJSON(&user); err != nil {
        response.Error(ctx, err)
    }
    db.Model(&user).Updates(user)
    response.Success(ctx, user)
}
```

That might work because the old values + the changes (written into the struct by `BindJSON`) might be able to pass validation.

Generally speaking, this pattern isn't going to help you for long in Go.

Using the same struct for two different purposes: representation of the entity model and representation of the messages in your API that pertain to the model, will end up giving you trouble sooner or later. These tend to be slightly different, as for example you might eventually have fields that are only exposed internally or, as you have encountered, you have validation that doesn't make sense for all use cases.

For this problem what would help you is to create a new struct to represent the update user message:

```golang
package messages

type UpdateUser struct {
    FirstName string    `json:"firstName"`
    LastName  string    `json:"lastName"`
    ... fields that are updatable with appropriate validation tags
}

func (u *UpdateUser) ToModel() *model.User {
    return &model.User{
       FirstName: u.FirstName,
       LastName: u.LastName,
       ...
    }
}
```

Then use that as to validate your request model, then turn it into a `model.User` for the update:

```golang
func Update(ctx *gin.Context) {
    userID := ctx.Param("userId")
    user := models.User{}
    db, _ := database.GetDB()
    if err := db.First(&user, userID).Error; err != nil {
        response.Error(ctx, err)
        return
    }
    updateUser := messages.UpdateUser{}
    if err := ctx.BindJSON(&updateUser); err != nil {
        response.Error(ctx, err)
    }
    //fmt.Printf("%v", updateUser)
    db.Model(&user).Updates(updateUser.ToModel())
    response.Success(ctx, user)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use an ORM like Gorm in your project, it is recommended to use viewmodel structs for your requests and responses. Because the structure of your database tables are mostly different then your rest api models. Data binding and validation are easier with viewmodel structs.